# Error: write EPIPE when running Jest tests on Gitlab CI's personal VPS

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

So, what I'm trying to do now is simple, create a job at Gitlab CI to run tests that I've made on my own personal VPS. I am using NestJS as my backend. The problem is, for some reason one/some of the test returned a `write EPIPE` error. Also, the only pattern I get is that the error only occurred for the test that's uploading image using multipart form but not consistently occurred, so like when I ran 3 times, sometimes `write EPIPE` only occurred 1 time, sometimes twice, sometimes none.

Here is my code snippets for uploading image using multipart form on the test:

```
it('should be able to upload image', () => {
    return request(myHost)
      .post('/upload-image')
      .expect(200)
      .attach('image', './testimage.jpg')
      .then((res): any => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual({});
      });
  });
```

For additional information, `testimage.jpg` is only **13.9kB**, so it's not a big file.

My node version: `14.16.0`, Jest version: `26.6.3`, NestJS version: `7.6.15`,and Ubuntu version: `20.04`.

What I've tried is installing `libpng-dev` package, `libfontconfig` package, and running tests using `-- --silent` tag and all of it is not working.

Comment: I had a simular problem, but I missed an await at some part. If you increase the image size it should be occurs more often, because the process takes more time and jest just finished. It could be happen only on gitlab, because the system there is slower. To reproduce it on my local system I use the jest client option --runInBand, then it use only one thread

Comment: @CordlessWool I finally got it working already, see my answer below. Also, thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working by setting the `Connection` header to be `keep-alive` to the tests that has that `write EPIPE` error. The best possible explanation I can give is when the image is uploading, the connection somehow got closed, so the upload process is stopped. That explains why there is no error when I added `console.log(err)` to the test and also there's no error on my backend side.

The EPIPE error explanations also mentioned this, which can be seen here:

[image: EPIPE Explanation]

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html, on the Common System Errors section.

Some part of the issue that I don't understand is why would the other upload image tests did not encounter this EPIPE error. I had like for sure more than 20 tests that have the upload image part, but only like < 10 encountered it. Besides that, the < 10 tests are randomized too, meaning like not all tests inside this group will 100% encountered it when they were tested.

For example, I have 20 tests for uploading an image, named `test1`, `test2`, and so on. For some reason, only some tests encountered the EPIPE error, let's say only `test1` to `test8` got it (in the real case, the test that got it is random). Then between `test1` and `test8`, sometimes they also got it, sometimes they don't, but the range is always the same (at the first run, the tests who got the EPIPE error was `test1`, `test3`, `test5`, `test6`. at the second run, the tests who got it could be different from the first one, which is `test1`, `test3`, `test5`, `test7`, and `test8`, but never went out of `test8`).

Perhaps someone can explain this.